# ViewGroup only intercept touch event if child does not

Tags: android, events, event-handling, touch, intercept

I have a `viewgroup` that I want to scroll manually, but I only want to enter tracking/scrolling mode it if the initial down press is not consumed by one of the children. Is there an easy way to check if one of the children wants the touch event?

The natural flow of `onInterceptTouchEvent` seems to be in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the child view to consume the event, just return false on its onTouch.
That should propagate the event to the parent.

Comment: The thing is I do want the child view to consume the event, if it wants it. However if there is not touch target, then I want the parent to consume it.